# WebdriverIO with Appium Service access to BrowserStack using corporate network issue

Tags: javascript, mobile, browserstack, wdio, browserstack-app-automate

We are trying to connect to Browserstack App Automate using WDIO(Appium Service).
But we are getting below error

```
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hub-cloud.browserstack.com
```

We got a confirmation that its not use proxy for relevant team.

We are using BrowserStack Local with all proxy info and credential as below

```
BrowserStackLocal.exe --key {KEY} --proxy-host {proxy} --proxy-port {port} --proxy-user {USERNAME}  --proxy-pass {Password} --force-local --force-prox
```

even we have tried with global agents. Still no luck.

Any way we can force export **startWebDriverSession** to use proxy can solve I feel.

Any suggestion is appreciated.